# Jquery links to submit form

Tags: jquery

I have a form with several stages, I need to make jquery submit the form when the link on the left of the pags is clicked:

```
<a href='?stage=1' class='page-left-btn'>Stage 1</a>
<a href='?stage=2' class='page-left-btn'>Stage 2</a>
<a href='?stage=3' class='page-left-btn'>Stage 3</a>
<a href='?stage=4' class='page-left-btn'>Stage 4</a>

<form id='stageform' action='myurl'>
<!-- form content here which is dynamically dispalyed with php based on the current      stage
</form>
```

Now I have the following jquery to submit the form when a link is clicked but it wont work and I can work out for the life of me why it wont work.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('a.page-left-btn').click( function() {
    $('#stageform').submit();
});
```

I can get this to work if I use a clickable div like this:

```
 <div  class='page-left-btn'>stage 1</div>
```

and this jQuery but I have no way to pass the new url to the page ?

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
$('.page-left-btn').click( function() {
    $('#stageform').submit();
});
```

Am I selecting the link incorrectly, Can anyone help, Im sure its something simple I am just overlooking

Thanks in advance

Comment: in order to the `form` be submitted, you need an `action` on the form... plus, use `preventDefault()` in order to avoid your page to load it again and all will be fine. - An easy way to see if you are invoking the method, is to add `console.log('here');` inside your `click` event... and open the console... you will see that is being invoked correctly or not.

Comment: on click of a anchor tag, the submit submit should be  clicked right instead of redirecting to the url mentioned in `href`

Comment: thankyou both for your replys. Maybe I never explained it properly. what I am asking is how do I select all links with a certain class ie is this part correct $('a.page-left-btn').click( function() {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind some js code to an anchor tag then you have to stop the default behavior of the anchor which is to take you to the next page specified in the link's href.

So change to this:

```
$('a.page-left-btn').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <---this should be done if your selector is anchor
    $('#stageform').submit();
});
```

[About event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: Ah this is very interesting thankyou. It submits the form the first time i clickk any of the links. But it only works once. and no matter how many times I click the links the page no longer changes. any ideas

Comment: when your form submits it redirects you to a new page so on that page.... is this code available?

Comment: ye it just sumits to the same page,the form action is action=''   :)

Comment: okay then what is the current url then,  is it something like `yoursite.com?state=1`

Comment: ye thats it, the page is yoursite.com?stage=1 when the link is clicked it submits the form and then changes the url to say ?stage=2 but then it wont work anymore and the clicks do dothing